# How to download a file to a specific path using wget as a Dockerfile run command?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

My app directory structure look like this:

```
Root/
    app.py
    requirements.txt

    imageHelpers/
        helpers.py
        config.yml
        model.pth
```

Instead of copying my `model.pth` to the server, I want to download it from the web while building the container. I want my `model.pth` to have the exact path as `imageHelpers/model.pth`. What should be the path for `wget -O PATH_TO_MODEL URL`?
Below is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /fast_api_test

COPY ./requirements.txt /fast_api_test/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r /fast_api_test/requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git' \
    && wget -q -O /imageHelpers/model.pth https://MY_URL/model.pth

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["uvicorn",  "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

Using `AWS` + `Ubuntu` if that's required.

when I run `sudo docker build -t fast_api .` , it gives me error:

```
/fast_api_test/imageHelpers/model.pth: No such file or directory

The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --upgrade -r /fast_api_test/requirements.txt     && python -m pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'     && wget -q -O /fast_api_test/imageHelpers/model.pth https://MY_URL/model.pth' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Do you see an error?

Comment: Can you show where the Dockerfile lives in your app directory structure?

Comment: Same place as `requirements.txt` and `app.py`

Answer (score 1):

COPY (like ADD) tries to copy from OUTSIDE the image INTO the image.

as the file is downloaded INSIDE the image already by wget, you need to use the commandline cp command

try this:

```
RUN cp <downloaded_file> /fast_api_test
COPY . /fast_api_test
```

Comment: You still need the `COPY` to get the rest of the application into the image.

Comment: yes, (edited) hope it satisfies your case